Device ownership on meta quest 2 and quest 3
I am able to take device ownership in other VR and Android devices via adb command
dpm set-device-owner --name "My Device Owner" packagename/adminReceiverClass
but when I am using same command in meta quest VR devices it is shows an error.
Error:

Not allowed to set the device owner because there are already some accounts on the device.

WHY
Because it have pre meta accounts (meta horizon profiles) and these accounts automatically available after factory reset.
What I Want
I want to remove that account before to take device-ownership via ADB and programmatically or any other way to remove that account.
Note
In market there are many companies provide MDM solution with VR devices and they are capable to remove that account but I don't know what am I missing to get device ownership in meta VR devices
